# MYSQL query to grab signal names while excluding anything inside a URL?

Tags: mysql

I am trying to create lists of different technical terms from my forum. Model numbers, signal numbers, specific chipsets, etc. The one that is most difficult, are signals. Signals are in this format - `PPV_SIGNAL_NAME` or `PP5_VDDIO_XO` - stuff followed by underscores

I have created this mysql query to grab every signal from every message in every thread on my forum and consolidate it into a csv file for me, which is great. However, it includes junk within a URL, since URLs commonly have underscores between text. :(

```
(SELECT DISTINCT TRIM(
    CASE
        WHEN CHAR_LENGTH(REGEXP_SUBSTR(message, '[A-Za-z0-9]{1,7}(_[A-Za-z0-9]{1,7})+')) >= 3
        THEN REGEXP_SUBSTR(message, '[A-Za-z0-9]{1,7}(_[A-Za-z0-9]{1,7})+')
    END
) FROM xf_post)
UNION
(SELECT DISTINCT TRIM(
    CASE
        WHEN CHAR_LENGTH(REGEXP_SUBSTR(title, '[A-Za-z0-9]{1,7}(_[A-Za-z0-9]{1,7})+')) >= 3
        THEN REGEXP_SUBSTR(title, '[A-Za-z0-9]{1,7}(_[A-Za-z0-9]{1,7})+')
    END
) FROM xf_thread)

INTO OUTFILE 'signal_names.csv'
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
ENCLOSED BY '"'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n';
```

So if there's a URL like https://google.com/pixel_phone_4_sale/discount.html , it includes `pixel_phone_4_sale` in my list, even though I don't want that.

I can tell the query to ignore any message with https in it by adding `WHEN message NOT LIKE '%https://%'` , but that misses every signal in that message too. Let's say someone says "If you want to read about PM_PWRMGMT_SLP_R, check out this website: https://power_rail_education.com " , it will exclude the entire message simply because it had a URL in it

Is what I am asking for even possible, or should I just cave and do this manually? There's over 9000 entries.

edit: I cave, doing this in mysql was way too pigheaded, stubborn, and dumb of me. I am trying again with python. Let's see if this works. Will report back if it does!!

```
import pandas as pd
import pymysql
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import html
import re

# Function to remove bold & italics tags and URLs
def clean_text(text):
    text = re.sub(r'\[/?[bi]\]', '', text)  # Remove BBCode tags
    url_pattern = r'http[s]?://(?:[a-zA-Z]|[0-9]|[$-_@.&+]|[!*\\(\\),]|(?:%[0-9a-fA-F][0-9a-fA-F]))+'
    text = re.sub(url_pattern, '', text)    # Remove URLs
    return text

# Function to remove HTML tags
def remove_html_tags(text):
    return BeautifulSoup(text, 'html.parser').get_text()

# Function to decode HTML entities
def decode_html_entities(text):
    return html.unescape(text)

# Database connection parameters
db_params = {
    'host': '127.0.0.1',
    'user': 'me',
    'password': 'lookitsme',
    'db': 'randomdb'
}

# Initialize a list to store DataFrames
dataframes = []

try:
    # Connect to the database
    connection = pymysql.connect(**db_params)

    # Fetch the list of thread_ids
    thread_ids_query = "SELECT thread_id FROM xf_thread;"
    thread_ids_df = pd.read_sql(thread_ids_query, connection)

    # Loop through each thread_id
    for thread_id in thread_ids_df['thread_id']:
        # Dynamic SQL query for each thread
        thread_query = f"""
        SELECT
            p.thread_id,
            t.title,
            p.post_id,
            p.message
        FROM
            xf_post AS p
        JOIN
            xf_thread AS t ON p.thread_id = t.thread_id
        WHERE
            p.thread_id = {thread_id};
        """
        # Fetch data for each thread
        df = pd.read_sql(thread_query, connection)

        # Data Cleaning
        df['message'] = df['message'].apply(remove_html_tags)
        df['message'] = df['message'].apply(decode_html_entities)
        df['message'] = df['message'].apply(clean_text)
        df['title'] = df['title'].apply(remove_html_tags)
        df['title'] = df['title'].apply(decode_html_entities)
        df['title'] = df['title'].apply(clean_text)

        # Append the DataFrame to the list
        dataframes.append(df)

finally:
    # Close the database connection
    connection.close()

# Function to find matches using regular expression
def find_regex_matches(text, pattern):
    if pd.isna(text):
        return []
    return re.findall(pattern, text)

# Concatenate all DataFrames in the list
all_threads_df = pd.concat(dataframes, ignore_index=True)

# Regular expression pattern
regex_pattern = r'[A-Za-z0-9]{1,10}(_[A-Za-z0-9]{1,10})+'

# Search in 'title' and 'message' columns
titles_matches = all_threads_df['title'].apply(find_regex_matches, pattern=regex_pattern)
messages_matches = all_threads_df['message'].apply(find_regex_matches, pattern=regex_pattern)

# Flatten the lists and get distinct values
all_matches = set()
for matches_list in titles_matches:
    all_matches.update(matches_list)
for matches_list in messages_matches:
    all_matches.update(matches_list)

# Convert to DataFrame
distinct_matches_df = pd.DataFrame(list(all_matches), columns=['Distinct Values'])

# Save to CSV
distinct_matches_df.to_csv('signal_names.csv', index=False)

print("Distinct matches saved to signal_names.csv")
```

Comment: you've showed one type of thing you want to not match, but not enough about the things you *do* want to match to be able to distinguish.  are signals always uppercase and the url parts always lower case?  what comes or never comes before and after signals?

Comment: My apologies for the poor explanation. The URLs are a mixture of upper and lowercase, and same for the signals. The thing that defines signals is that they have underscores between the different parts. Sometimes it's letters, sometimes numbers, sometimes a mixture. Usually a space occurs before a signal, and a comma/period/blank/semicolon/colon/some other punctuation occurs after.

Comment: MySQL's string processing is very limited. I would never think of trying to do this in MySQL, I'd do it in the client programming language.

Comment: usually a space is before a signal?  what cases is it not?  sounds like your definition of what's a signal matches what's in urls, so you will need to figure out a definitive way to tell from context

Comment: You are absolutely correct that trying to do this in mysql alone was shortsighted, stubborn, and dumb. I am trying in python now, wish me luck with what I edited my original post to include!

Answer (score 0):

One way to remove all URLs from the text passages would be to `regexp_replace()` them with an empty string. After that apply the `regexp_substr()` function:

```
select regexp_substr(regexp_replace(
       'If you want to read about PM_PWRMGMT_SLP_R, check out this website: https://power_rail_education.com',
                      'https://[a-z_0-9/.]+',''),'[A-Za-z0-9]+(_[A-Za-z0-9]+)+')
```

Check out this little snippet https://extendsclass.com/mysql/e1ea79e for a demo.